# IntelliJ render ANSI colors in plain text file

Tags: intellij-idea, ansi-colors

I just learned that it's possible to color output in java console using ANSI escape sequences. The below for instance:

```
final String RED_COLOR_CODE = "\u001B[31m";
final String RESET_CODE = "\u001B[0m";
System.out.println(RED_COLOR_CODE + "This is red output" + RESET_CODE);
```

would print 'This is red output' to the console in red.

If I use a PrintStream to print exactly the same to a plain text file:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("foo/log.log");
ps.println(RED_COLOR_CODE + "This is red output" + RESET_CODE);
ps.close();
```

and then I open the file in Intellij editor I get ' [31mThis is red output [0m' in black. Is there a configuration or maybe a plugin for IntelliJ that would allow the rendering of ANSI escape sequences in the editor similarly to console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested, [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9707-ansi-highlighter)'s a plugin that should do while on the wait for official support by JetBrains.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible at the moment, vote for this related request:

- [IDEA-172142](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172142) ANSI Color and formatting support for .log files

See also [this forum discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000194544-Bash-formatting-in-log-files).

Comment: seems like it'll take forever, I'm the first voter :)